# Desired form of eigenvectors For the matrix $ L:=\left[ \begin {array}{cc} -i\lambda-(i/2)a&c\\-c&i \lambda+(i/2)a\end {array} \right]$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For the matrix
$$ L=\left[ \begin {array}{cc} -i\lambda-(i/2)a&c\\-c&i
\lambda+(i/2)a\end {array} \right],$$

we have the eigenvalues

$$\operatorname{eigenvalues} = \left[ \begin {array}{c} 1/2\,\sqrt {-{a}^{2}-4\,\lambda\,a-4\,{c}^{2
}-4\,{\lambda}^{2}}\\ -1/2\,\sqrt {-{a}^{2}-4\,
\lambda\,a-4\,{c}^{2}-4\,{\lambda}^{2}}\end {array} \right],$$

and the corresponding eigenvectors
$$\operatorname{eigenvectors} =  \left[ \begin {array}{cc} \,{\dfrac {2c}{ia+2\,i\lambda+\sqrt {-{a}^{2
}-4\,\lambda\,a-4\,{c}^{2}-4\,{\lambda}^{2}}}}&\,{\dfrac {2c}{ia+2\,i
\lambda-\sqrt {-{a}^{2}-4\,\lambda\,a-4\,{c}^{2}-4\,{\lambda}^{2}}}}
\\ 1&1\end {array} \right]
:=\left[\begin{array}{cc}\alpha& \beta\end{array}\right]$$

But $\alpha$ and $\beta$ should be

$$\alpha = \left[\begin{array}{c}c \\ i(\frac{1}{2}a+\lambda+d_1)\end{array}\right],\quad\beta = \left[\begin{array}{c}i(\frac{1}{2}a+\lambda+d_1)\\c\end{array}\right],$$

where $d_1=\sqrt {{a}^{2
}+4\,\lambda\,a+4\,{c}^{2}+4\,{\lambda}^{2}}$, and $a,\;c,\;\lambda$ are non-zero. How can we get these eigenvectors?

Comment: When you say '$\alpha$ and $\beta$ should be ...' are you sure these are right? For $\alpha$ I get the vector $(c, -i(\frac{1}{2}a + \lambda + \frac{1}{2} d1))$.

Comment: @ElliotHerrington, how about $\beta$?